# rails 3: how to abort delivery method in actionmailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In my mailer controller, under certain conditions (missing data) we abort sending the email.

How do I exit the controller method without still rendering a view in that case?

> return if @some_email_data.nil?

Doesn't do the trick since the view is still rendered (throwing an error every place I try to use @some_email_data unless I add a lot of nil checks)

And even if I do the nil checks, it complains there's no 'sender' (because I supposed did a 'return' before getting to the line where I set the sender and subject.

Neither does `render ... return`

Basically, RETURN DOESN'T RETURN inside a mailer method!

Comment: Can you paste some relative code?

Comment: Does return from a mailer work in Rails 2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just encountered same thing here.

My solution was following:

```
module BulletproofMailer
  class BlackholeMailMessage < Mail::Message
    def self.deliver
      false
    end
  end

  class AbortDeliveryError < StandardError
  end

  class Base < ActionMailer::Base

    def abort_delivery
      raise AbortDeliveryError
    end

    def process(*args)
      begin
        super *args
      rescue AbortDeliveryError
        self.message = BulletproofMailer::BlackholeMailMessage
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using these wrapper mailer would look like this:

```
class EventMailer < BulletproofMailer::Base
  include Resque::Mailer
  def event_created(event_id)
    begin
      @event = CalendarEvent.find(event_id)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      abort_delivery
    end
  end
end
```

It is also [posted](http://dmitry.shaposhnik.name/canceling-mail-delivery-from-within-mailer) in my blog.

Comment: I still believe this could be done way easier, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Eisenhorn There is - have a look at my answer.

Comment: I have an ApplicationMailer base class for all of my emails (much like ApplicationController) and I put this functionality in there.

Answer (score 28):

A much simpler solution than the accepted answer would be something like:

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def some_method
    if @some_email_data.nil?
      self.message.perform_deliveries = false
    else
      mail(...)  
    end  
  end
end
```

If you're using Rails 3.2.9 (or later things even better) - there you can finally conditionally call `mail()`. Here's the related [GitHub thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7761). Now the code can be reworked like this:

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def some_method
    unless @some_email_data.nil?
      mail(...)  
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: And how do you test this out come?

Comment: Seems like in Rails 3.2.9 you might be able to see `mail.should be_a_kind_of NullMail` but I still don't know how to test it in Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Added with a little playing around, I figured out you can do this in Rails 3.2.8: `mail.perform_deliveries.should_not be`

Comment: To test that nothing was delivered: `expect { described_class.my_email_method.deliver_now }.not_to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mail.perform_deliveries`? `self.message.perform_deliveries = false` doesn't work for me. But `mail.perform_deliveries` works! It's also mentioned on the Rails Guide–http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks

Comment: So you would need to stub out every mailer method in your application? Sounds…not good.

Answer (score 9):

I've found this method that seems the least-invasive, as it works across all mailer methods without requiring you to remember to catch an error.  In our case, we just want a setting to completely disable mailers for certain environments.  Tested in Rails 6, although I'm sure it'll work just fine in Rails 5 as well, maybe lower.

```rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  class AbortDeliveryError < StandardError; end

  before_action :ensure_notifications_enabled
  rescue_from AbortDeliveryError, with: -> {}

  def ensure_notifications_enabled
    raise AbortDeliveryError.new unless <your_condition>
  end

  ...

end
```

The empty lambda causes Rails 6 to just return an `ActionMailer::Base::NullMail` instance, which doesn't get delivered (same as if your mailer method didn't call `mail`, or returned prematurely).

Comment: Thanks @mpowered, I will try this technique! I've been trying `message.perform_deliveries = false` and `return ActionMailer::Base::NullMail.new` but it doesn't seem to help and I still get `Postmark::ApiInputError` errors with `Zero recipients specified`. Hopefully `raise AbortDeliveryError` will finally solve this issue, it's been bugging me for years!

Answer (score 1):

Setting `self.message.perform_deliveries = false` did not work for me.

I used a similar approach as some of the other answers - using error handling to control the flow and prevent the mail from being sent.

The example below is aborting mail from being sent in non-Production ENVs to non-whitelisted emails, but the helper method logic can be whatever you need for your scenario.

```
class BaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  class AbortedMailer < StandardError; end

  def mail(**args)
    whitelist_mail_delivery(args[:to])
    super(args)
  rescue AbortedMailer
    Rails.logger.info "Mail aborted! We do not send emails to external email accounts outside of Production ENV"
  end

  private

  def whitelist_mail_delivery(to_email)
    return if Rails.env.production?

    raise AbortedMailer.new unless internal_email?(to_email)
  end

  def internal_email?(to_email)
    to_email.include?('@widgetbusiness.com')
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

I just clear the @to field and return, so deliver aborts when it doesn't have anything there.  (Or just return before setting @to).

Comment: It may abort but you know this is a crap answer. If there's CC/BCC the email will still go out and additionally, since this is a hack there's no guarantee that this will not throw huge errors in the future.

Comment: it's more elegant than the (current) top solution.  The great elegance vs. complication tradeoff. Rails clearly needs to add something.

Comment: "Elegant", love it :-P

Answer (score -5):

I haven't spent much time with rails 3 but you could try using

`redirect_to some_other_route`

alternatively, if you're really just checking for missing data you could do a js validation of the form fields and only submit if it passes.

Comment: there's no user or session to redirect to... (the method is called by delayed job in response to some event triggers) we need the method to simply stop in its tracks